# Did Leonardo DiCaprio accidentally cut his hand and smear blood to Kerry Washington's face in Django Unchained?

Tags: django-unchained, quentin-tarantino

In *Django Unchained* there is a scene where Calvin Candie (Leonardo DiCaprio) cut his hand and then smeared the blood on Broomhilda's (Kerry Washington) face.

Did DiCaprio really accidentally cut his own hand there or was that part of the script and done with effects? There is a cut between these two events, which leads me to believe it was not an accident.

Comment: What is your question about - cutting the hand or smearing his own blood on Kerry's face?

Comment: @Mouvier I clarified the question a little more.

Answer (score 5):

All sources claim that DiCaprio really cut his hand so it seems to be true and there is no reason to think otherwise.

Here's a video with [Christoph Waltz talking about that incident](https://youtu.be/Qzo7n0NSqOc?t=89).

Comment: The problem with that video is that it looks like Waltz was answering the question as to whether or not the blood on his hand was real.  The reason: When he answered as to why, he elaborates that he didn't know and he did a take where it didn't happen, and then another take where he accidentally hit the glass. _That's answering where the blood came from, not whether or not they put it on her face._ There is *no way* IMO that Tarantino would risk the legal trouble with SAG-AFTRA, Kerry Washington, and for God's sake _the studio_ over that when fake blood works and can even allow MULTIPLE takes.

Answer (score 5):

It was real.  A simple Google of "Dicaprio cut hand" would have dug this out:

Additionally, it's in a WatchMojo list of on set injuries:

Comment: This only answers _half_ the question.  Yes, he cut his hand.  No, he did not smear it on the actresses face.

Comment: The question, *as asked*, was, "Did DiCaprio really accidentally cut his own hand there or was that part of the script and done with effects?"

Comment: The answer, as it is now, could use an edit to answer the second part of the question, though.

Comment: From what I've seen, he definitely cut his hand, and he definitely smeared blood on the actress's face. The question at hand is, "Did he smear his real blood on her face, or did they reset with fake blood?" I have not seen anything that answers that question.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, he really did that. It wasn't scripted, but Quentin Tarantino liked the take so much that he kept it in the film.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? Should we just take your word for it?